# Uploading job fails on the same file that was uploaded successfully before

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running regular uploading job to upload csv into BigQuery. The job runs every hour. According to recent fail log, it says:

```
Error: [REASON] invalid [MESSAGE] Invalid argument: service.geotab.com [LOCATION] File: 0 / Offset:268436098 / Line:218637 / Field:2
Error: [REASON] invalid [MESSAGE] Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0. [LOCATION]
```

I went to line 218638 (the original csv has a headline, so I assume 218638 should be the actual failed line, let me know if I'm wrong) but it seems all right. I checked according table in BigQuery, it has that line too, which means I actually successfully uploaded this line before.

Then why does it causes failure recently?

```
project id: red-road-574
Job ID:   Job_Upload-7EDCB180-2A2E-492B-9143-BEFFB36E5BB5
```

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that there was a problem with the data in your file, where it didn't match the schema.

The error message says it occurred at `File: 0 / Offset:268436098 / Line:218637 / Field:2`. This means the first file (it looks like you just had one), and then the chunk of the file starting at 268436098 bytes from the beginning of the file, then the 218637th line from that file offset.

The reason for the offset portion is that bigquery processes large files in parallel in multiple workers. Each file worker starts at an offset from the beginning of the file. The offset that we include is the offset that the worker started from.

From the rest of the error message, it looks like the string `service.geotab.com` showed up in the second field, but the second field was a number, and `service.geotab.com` isn't a valid number. Perhaps there was a stray newline?

You can see what the lines looked like around the error by doing:

`cat <yourfile> | tail -c +268436098 | tail -n +218636 | head -3`

This will print out three lines... the one before the error (since I used -n +218636 instead of +218637), the one that had the error, and the next line as well.

Note that if this is just one line in the file that has a problem, you may be able to work around the issue by specifying [`maxBadRecords`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load).

Comment: so 218637 is not from the beginning of the file, but from offset 268436098 ?

Comment: And, do you know what's the Windows command line that equivalent to "cat <yourfile> | tail -c +268436098 | tail -n +218636 | head -3" ?